# Elasticsearch how to support transaction involving multiple documents

Tags: elasticsearch

i use elasticsearch,and Denormalizing Data,like

```
PUT /my_index/user/1
{
"name": "John Smith",
"email": "john@smith.com",
"dob": "1970/10/24"
}

PUT /my_index/blogpost/2
{
"title": "Relationships",
"body": "It's complicated...",
"user": {
"id": 1,
"name": "John Smith"
}
}
```

but the problem is that Elasticsearch does not support ACID transactions. Changes to individual documents are ACIDic, but not changes involving multiple documents.if i want to change /my_index/user/1 and /my_index/blogpost/2 user name at one transaction,if one error it will rollback, how to do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are no transactions in ES and never will according to inside sources.

The best way to achieve what you want is to make your [updates in bulk](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) and then check the response of each individual responses.

```
POST _bulk
{"index": {"_index": "my_index", "_type": "user", "_id": "1"}}
{ "name": "John Smith", "email": "john@smith.com", "dob": "1970/10/24" }
{"index": {"_index": "my_index", "_type": "blogpost", "_id": "2"}}
{ "title": "Relationships", "body": "It's complicated...", "user": { "id": 1, "name": "John Smith" }}
```

When your client gets the responses, it should check the `items` array and make sure that each item `status` is 200 (updated) or 201 (created). If that's the case, your bulk "transaction" was properly committed, if not, then everything with status 200 or 201 was committed otherwise the commit failed.

Comment: What if we have update in a DB table and add/update index in ES inside a transaction block? If the DB operation failed, will the ES action rollback? What is recommended approach to handle this scenario?

Comment: @ValsarajViswanathan I will recommend you to only update Elasticsearch if your DB operation is successful and do it in asynchronous way, then you can have a retry mechanism.
also you can think of different approach to update elastic with binlog.

Comment: ES `_bulk` operation has nothing in common with transaction and an ACID principles

Comment: @Alex-Bogdanov that's exactly what I said in my answer :-) not sure why you downvoted