# Is there any way to use Transactional manager with the Elasticsearch Repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-transactions

I am using elastic search in my project,  there is one flow where i am updating multiple indices which are dependent on each other, I have one question while updating one index suppose it gets failed due to some error, how can i rollback the commit from other indices?
Excample:
I have one index(JobInformation) which are storing basic information of the jobs and other index(JobMetadata) is storing metadata of the jobs. Suppose while creating a new job data gets successfully committed in JobInformation index but while committing in JobMetadata it gets failed, in this case how can i rollback the data from JobInformation index?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Currently, There is no way to support transaction in elastic-search. You need to write some custom logic to rollback . You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51075259/12013107